# Grouping units more sanely

Tags: units

Would it be possible to get Mathematica to group units more sanely. For example the calculation:

```
m = Quantity["Meters"];
D[
  D[
   Sin[p] (m),
   Quantity[p, "Seconds"]] ,
  Quantity[p, "Seconds"]] // Expand
```

This gives an visual output:

```
(-1 m/s^2) Sin[p]
```

however it would be more natural to show:

```
 -Sin[p](m/s^2)
```

I there a way to make this happen.

Notes:

- Expand is strictly not necessary in this case but can nice be in more complex cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to work

```
m = Quantity[#, "Meters"] &;
D[D[Sin[p] // m, Quantity[p, "Seconds"]], 
  Quantity[p, "Seconds"]] // Expand
```

Or you transform by hand

```
nonQuantitiesAsMagnitudes[expr_] := 
 expr /. x_ Quantity[y_, unit_] :> Quantity[x y, unit]

m = Quantity["Meters"];
D[
  D[
   Sin[p] (m),
   Quantity[p, "Seconds"]] ,
  Quantity[p, "Seconds"]] // Expand //nonQuantitiesAsMagnitudes
```

Comment: Yeah that's it. Still think that Mathematicas syntax for units is atrocious. My engineering students seem to come up with hives about this. But i think they can live with this. What does the **&;** do?

Comment: Terribly late reply, but `&` makes the preceding term into a pure function, while the `;` ends the statement and suppresses output. This means you can use m as a function, where `#` represents the first argument: `m[1]` would evaluate to `Quantity[1,"Meters"]`. The `//` in the second line is a postfix function application, so the `m` is used as `m[Sin[p]]`.